# Can pheromones in perfume be formulated to cause agitation?

Tags: physiology, brain

I generally don't care for female perfume. I have very sensitive olfactory receptors and in general, I just find perfume overwhelming.

A couple weeks ago, my wife of almost 14 years and I were shopping. As has happened many times before, she asked me to smell a perfume (Play it Rock by Playboy) to see if I liked it. Shockingly, on first whiff, though still overwhelming, I quite liked it. So she bought it.

Now, when she wears it, I *do* find the aroma pleasing, however I find myself getting quite agitated, depressed and even overcome with jealousy and paranoia.

Obviously, there are lots of psychological factors in play :

- Perfume's primary purpose *is* to arouse and attract men
- She almost only uses it when there *are* going to be other men around
- It *is* playboy, subtly indicating the promotion of promiscuity

However my internal reactions are so intense I can't help but conclude there something more physiological triggering/intensifying them.

- Could the perfume's pheromones be slightly misformulated to cause
  this reaction?
- Would the same pheromones that arouse a man also inherently trigger the fear of the arousal of others?
- Is it possible that my pheromone "sense" is also heightened like my sense of smell, causing an abnormal reaction specifically in me?

<sub>Note : I can't find official documentation that the playboy perfumes apply pheromonology (Yes, I did just make up that word), but I have found them listed by other sources in sections of perfumes that do, but Playboy perfumes seem to be priced drastically less than the rest of the pheromoned perfumes.</sub>

Comment: You are really getting at psychology here as opposed to the biological question(s). As written, it's really too general. There is no way to answer a question about your specifically or anyone else.

Comment: @kmm - This question presents a scenario in which the sample group (me) is far too specialized to draw a conclusion. Thus, presenting some, specifically physiological (biological), hypotheses is seeking response from the biology community. You state that this is getting at psychology, which is true, however it's specifically the biological causes of psychological response.  I'd also like to note that ALL psychology boils down to biology.

Comment: The point is that your question is too broad as written, about your specific experiences rather than general phenomena. If you have a specific biological question about pheromones and behavior, then feel free to edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Insects generate and respond to pheromones. But despite what sci-fi TV might have told you, there is no evidence that humans make or respond to pheromones like that.  Humans don't have that good sense of smell, for one thing.

The fact that you know it's a Playboy brand of perfume is affecting you?  That's obviously not chemical, is psychological.

Also, historically, perfume was used just as much to mask unpleasant odors as it was to attract anyone.  When men go through puberty, their sweat changes odor.  That's not to attract other men.

If this perfume is affecting you emotionally it's psychological, not chemical.

Comment: Thank you! Your response shows notable intellect though you may have skimmed through my question a bit too hastily.
First, I was specifically highlighting the purely psychological components to consider. However, the experienced result seemed to outweigh the sum of their potential.
Second, perfume's primary purpose WAS for masking odor. I'd submit that WAS to prevent repulsion, thus attract. It's current iteration is simply more direct.
Finally, by simplest definition pheromones are chemicals released that affect an animal's own species. This definition leaves little room for human exemption.